# Mutually exclusive options in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-material2, angular-forms

Let me try to explain a little bit my situation...

I have a `<form>` that contains a `FormArray`. Every `FormArray` group has the "food" `control` and each of them is a `<select>`.

All the selects are populated by a **single** `array`.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

The options of each select must be exclusively selected... in other words,
the result in `FormArray` must contain only **unique** elements.

---

My actual code:

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <div>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="addItem()">
      <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>Add food
    </button>
  </div>
  <ng-container
    formArrayName="items"
    *ngFor="let item of formArray.controls; index as i"
  >
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-title>
        <h3>Item nº {{ i + 1 }}</h3>
        <button
          mat-mini-fab
          color="warn"
          matTooltip="Remove"
          type="button"
          (click)="removeItem(i)"
        >
          <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-card-title>

      <mat-card-content [formGroupName]="i">
        <mat-select
          formControlName="food"
          name="food"
          placeholder="Favorite food"
        >
          <mat-option
            [value]="food.value"
            *ngFor="let food of foods"
          >
            {{ food.viewValue }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

**Component:**

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  readonly foods: readonly Food[] = [
    { value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak' },
    { value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza' },
    { value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos' }
  ];
  readonly formArray = this.formBuilder.array([]);
  readonly formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    items: this.formArray
  });
  
  constructor(private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
  
  addItem(): void {
    this.formArray.push(
      this.formBuilder.group({
        food: ''
      })
    )
  }
  
  removeItem(index: number): void {
    this.formArray.removeAt(index);
  }
}
```

---

I want to know which is the best option to achieve this.

So far I think in 3 options:

1 - Disable options that have already been selected in another `<select>`;

2 - Create a custom validator and tell the user that he can't select an option in 2 or more selects.

3 - Completely remove the **selected** options from other selects.

I prefer the 1st. option, however I can't find a way to do this. Can someone show me something to start? I hope the question is clear enough.

Here's a [**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5mn6w).

Comment: I've found this (quite old) written in `jQuery`: http://rndnext.blogspot.com.br/2009/08/mutually-exclusive-html-select-elements.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just build my own solution:

I created a method to check if it should be disabled:

```
isOptionDisabled(value: string, index: number): boolean {
  const foodsFormArray = this.formArray.value as readonly FoodFormGroup[];
  const foundIndex = foodsFormArray.findIndex(({ food }) => food === value);

  return foundIndex !== -1 && foundIndex !== index;
}
```

So, in template...

```
...
<mat-option
  [disabled]="isOptionDisabled(food.value, i)"
  [value]="food.value"
  *ngFor="let food of foods"
...
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5mn6w-1fzj2z)

Isn't it an optimal solution? Maybe... if you have another option to do this, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by subscribing to the `valueChanges` of control,

```
this.formGroup.controls['items'].valueChanges.subscribe(
   d=>{
       _.remove(this.foods,(item)=>{return item=== d[0].food})
 })
```

Inside the subscription, remove the element from the array.

On Deletion, push the object to array again as below,

```
removeItem(index: number) {
      this.foods.push(this.formArray.controls[index].controls["food"].value);
      this.formArray.removeAt(index);
}
```

**[UPDATED PLUNKER FOR LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/CAyObuXfANyCW27Zma31?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. Whenever you select an option it's removed from the current select, so you have a blank selection. Just see your plunker..

Comment: @dev_054 Can you clearly explain the gap in my code.